# Azure web api publish stop opening browser once completed

Tags: azure, redirect, publish

When we publish a WEB API 2 to Azure, despite being a WEB API and not a WEB APP (Web site) after the publish is completed it opens the browser with the link but it leads nowhere since there's no resources available at the address of the WEB API 2.

Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 3
Azure SDK 2.9.5

How to avoid this redirection once a WEB API 2 is published ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question :).

Here's what you can do: Open up publish profile file under `Properties --> PublishProfiles` folder inside your project and comment the line which reads:

```
<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>Your website address would be listed here</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
```

Now when you publish, after publish the browser will not open the site.

Comment: Wow, perfect.  Thank you!